# HTML CSS: aligning elements Vertically on one line

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a user logged-in header which shows a greeting, a thumbnail of the user's profile picture (always a fixed size - 30x30) and a logout link. There are vertical separators between each piece of text and the photo.

```
<span>Hello [username]</span>
<span class="divider"></span>
<img src="/photo.jpg" />
<span class="divider"></span>
<a href="/logout">Logout</a>
```

Here is the result I am going for:

[image: Desired result]

.. but the height of the picture pushes all the other elements 'down' so I get this:

[image: Actual result]

How do I align these vertically - is there a way to do it without hard-coding px margins/padding for each element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrrite `vertical-align:middle`; or `vertical-align:top;`. Write like this :

```
img, span , a{
  vertical-align:middle
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/bB9vV/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think you will want to change the line-height of the divider using CSS.
Give the line-height a value equal to the height of your image.
Then you will need to center the text.

```
.divider{
line-height:30px;
}
```

**EDIT**
You may also need to align your image.
EXAMPLE   use {vertical-align:middle;} for your image

More info here [align image vertically](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_vertical-align)

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
img, .divider{float:left;}
.up{margin-bottom:15px; float:left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<span class='up'>Hello [username]</span>
<span class="divider"></span>
<img src="/photo.jpg" />
<span class="divider"></span>
<a class='up' href="/logout">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```